# python Socket localhost И connect по другой сети

Tags: python, сокет, localhost

Сделал в питоне socket с указанием IP ноутбука (получен командой ipconfig в cmd), который подключен к wifi от андроида1

Сделал приложение с клиентом, который должен подключаться (connect) к этому ip на ноуте. Если запустить это приложение на том же андроиде (то есть андроид1), с которого раздается wifi, то все работает. Но если взять другой андроид, который имеет другую сеть, то ничего не работает. Как позволить подключаться к ноуту?

Подключение следующее
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

Comment: Нужен код, настройки, которые ты применил. Лично мне трудно так ориентироваться, также я немного не понял вопроса.... ты хочешь сделать подключение к ноутбуку через сеть с телефона?

Comment: Вот код сервера
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(
    ('192.168.??.???',8888)
)

s.listen(5)

while 1:
    try:
        client,addr=s.accept()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        s.close()
        break
    else:
        result=client.recv(1024)
        print(result.decode('utf-8'),addr)

Comment: А это клиент
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(   (тот же IP, 8888))
s.send(b'my first')
s.close()
Я так понимаю вопрос в том, что надо сделать мой локалхост общедоступным, но как это сделать?Ноутбук уже подключен к сети одного андроида, Интернет от него.

Comment: А теперь создай новый вопрос, правильно оформи, правильно укажи на проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если я понял правильно, то вы собираетесь подключиться с [андрод, сеть1] к [ноутбук, сеть2].

Если это так, то вам придётся подключаться к (ip ноутбука, открытый порт), чтобы код сработал как надо. В таком случае нужно иметь открытый порт на компьютере. Открывая порт, вы откроете доступ к вашему устройству всем злоумышленникам, в том числе и троянам.

Чтобы посмотреть открытые порты на компьютере, нужно в консоли Windows прописать команду netstat -a